# ¿Cómo puedo unir estas dos consultas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Hola como puedo realizar la unión de estas dos consultas MySQL?

Esta son las dos

```
                 SELECT
                  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                    CONCAT(
                      'ifnull(SUM(case when corte = ''',
                      corte,
                      ''' then cantidad_corte end),0) AS `',
                      "Corte ",corte, '`'
                    )
                  ) INTO @sql
                FROM
                  vista_corte;
                SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT tipo, item AS "Nombre", proyecto, cantidad AS "Cantidad", valor_unitario AS "Valor Unitario", total AS "Valor Total", ', @sql, ' FROM                           vista_corte GROUP BY item');

                PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
                EXECUTE stmt;
                DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;



                   

         SELECT
          GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
            CONCAT(
              'ifnull(SUM(case when corte = ''',
              corte,
              ''' then valor end),0) AS `',
              "Valor ",corte, '`'
            )
          ) INTO @sql
        FROM
          vista_corte;
        SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' FROM vista_corte GROUP BY item');

        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Agradezco su ayuda, lo he intentado con UNION pero me genera error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es una de las maneras que he intentado pero me genera error, lo he puesto desde el primer FROM y me da el mismo error, le intentado de varias maneras pero me genera error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿y cuál es el error que te genera el uso de union?

Comment: Este amigo ya edito la publicación y te muestro

Comment: Por favor, usa texto en lugar de imágenes en tus preguntas para que sigan los estándares de la comunidad. Pásate por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas de lo que hablo.

Answer (score 0):

No me quedo muy claro el resultado que esperas. Te comento lo siguiente:
Para el `UNION` los **`N`** `SELECT` deben retornar el mismo número de columnas y mismo tipo de datos (que sean numero, string -digamos- en escencia).

Ahora bien tu 1er. `SELECT` en el `CONCAT` tiene **`item, proyecto,...`** y otros más; el 2do. no queda claro que debe contener.

Realiza lo siguiente; arma los dos SQL separados de tal forma que te devuelvan los datos que requieres y con las columnas con mismo tipo de datos.

Una vez que obtengas lo anterior ya les puedes aplicar el `UNION`; si es necesario uses el:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Te sugiero usar tablas temporales; unirlas y luego borrarlas. Te ilustro como puede ser a continuación:

```
-- Borrarmos las tablas primero
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TABLA1 CASCADE;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TABLA2 CASCADE;

-- Para crear la primer tabla
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TABLA1 SELECT [AQUI LAS COLUMNAS CORRECTAMENTE FORMADAS] FROM vista_corte  GROUP BY item;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


-- Para crear la segunda tabla
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TABLA2 SELECT [AQUI LAS COLUMNAS CORRECTAMENTE FORMADAS] FROM vista_corte  GROUP BY item;');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT * FROM TABLA1
UNION
SELECT * FROM TABLA2;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TABLA1 CASCADE;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TABLA2 CASCADE;
```

Lo primero es que logres el SQL `SELECT` con los datos como quieres obtenerlos.

En tú código de la imagen observa que el `UNION` lo tienes luego de un `SET`; así como el primer `SELECT` no devuelve datos por que los almacena en tu variable `@sql`.